# React.js passing down image link not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As indicated, I was trying to pass down an image link from the **internet**.

When I do this, the code does not give an error, but fails to load the image:

Parent component:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header imgLink="https://i.ibb.co/Q6q5F3x/profile.png" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child component:

```
const Header = (imgLink) => {
    return(
        <div className="header">
            <img className="profile-pic" src={imgLink} alt="Profile Pic"/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

When I simply use the image link as the img src without it being passed down from the parent component, it would work; but I would still like it to be passed down from the parent.

Any insight will help! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to destruct params in Header component.

```
const Header = ({imgLink}) =>
```

else it's just an props object:

```
const Header = (props) => {console.log(props.imgLink)}
```